# Data permanent storage in application development

Tags: android

During the development of an application program, I need to preserve and read an INT value. At the same time, once the value saved, it is no longer impacted from android system "Settings--- factory default---factory reset"

Now I want to save the value in nvram. Is there some way to preserve and read the nvram value in application layer?

Or it has memory space to preserve the value in application layer, and do not be impacted from android system "Settings--- factory default---factory reset"

I am not sure if the SD card is impacted by factory reset. If it is, when the SD card changed, the data is missing too.

Answer (score 0):

Internal is completely wiped on factory reset as far as I know. But the SD card is a valid path to take as it isn't directly affected. That said the user might clean the SD by himself...